# Logo is in the middle of the header though css is float right in the landing pages

Tags: html, css

https://www.winepeople.com.au/4270001

CSS

```
float: right
```

winepeople logo is in the people even though the css id declared as right. I couldnt figure it out. Please help

Comment: It is hard to understand the problem with which you need help.

Please consider adding images showing how the header is displaying and how you would like it to display along with any code examples you can provide.

This article explains how to ask a question in the way most likely to receive a helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.winepeople.com.au/jsp/offer/recr/au/wpe/offer_temp5.jsp?offerId=90800232&promoCode=3227001&offer=2018/june/3227001&utm_source=inside_golf&utm_medium=print&utm_campaign=3227001&utm_content=rec_insert_woto

Comment: header logo should be displayed as shown in the link.    https://www.winepeople.com.au/jsp/offer/recr/au/wpe/offer_temp5.jsp?offerId=90800232&promoCode=3227001&offer=2018/june/3227001&utm_source=inside_golf&utm_medium=print&utm_campaign=3227001&utm_content=rec_insert_woto

Comment: https://winepeople.com.au/4491001    Please consider this link for the reference.

Comment: Sudi, all of these headers are floating right. Can you confirm which page this is occurring on?

Comment: I am struggling in this page as the winepeople logo is in the middle . https://www.winepeople.com.au/4270001

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="header-logo" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
  <a href="/">
    <img src="/images/au/en/brands/wp/recr/WP_logo.gif" alt="Laithwaite's Wine" class="img-responsive pull-right">
  </a>
</div>
```

A combination of `.pull-right` on the image and a `.col-sm-offset-6` will work to get your desired result in most situations. There are many other possibilities.

I suggest you review the Bootstrap 4 layout grid docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

**Answer #2:**

Pertains to:
https://www.winepeople.com.au/jsp/offer/recr/au/wpe/offer_temp5.jsp?offerId=91100022&promoCode=4271001&offer=2018/november/4271001&utm_source=my241&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=4271001&utm_content=rec_xmas

This page has Grid CSS borrowed from Bootstrap, but does not seem to have the required media queries to isolate class behavior by screen size. Hence, you have a battle between `.col-xs-5` and `.col-sm-6`. The CSS will work if you remove your `.col-xs-5` class until your CSS library can be properly compiled.

HTML

```
<div class="header-container clearfix">
    <!-- Begin logo -->
    <div id="header-logo" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="/">
                    <img src="/images/au/en/brands/wp/recr/my241_logo.jpg" alt="My241" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
            </div>
 <!-- End logo -->
 <div class="col-xs-2 visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>
 <!-- Begin logo -->
    <div id="header-logo" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="/">
                    <img src="/images/au/en/brands/wp/recr/WP_logo.gif" alt="Laithwaite's Wine" class="img-responsive" style="float:right">
                    </a>
            </div>
    <!-- End logo -->
</div>
```

Should become:

```
<div class="header-container clearfix">
    <!-- Begin logo -->
    <div id="header-logo" class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="/">
                    <img src="/images/au/en/brands/wp/recr/my241_logo.jpg" alt="My241" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
            </div>
 <!-- End logo -->
 <div class="col-xs-2 visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>
 <!-- Begin logo -->
    <div id="header-logo" class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="/">
                    <img src="/images/au/en/brands/wp/recr/WP_logo.gif" alt="Laithwaite's Wine" class="img-responsive" style="float:right">
                    </a>
            </div>
    <!-- End logo -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please ignore the previous pages.

Comment: Above code works but both the logos are not in the same line.

Comment: In the future, it will be helpful to paste HTML snippets like I have provided in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the problem. You are awesome.

Comment: You're welcome @sudi. Please upvote the answer if I was able to help you.